# What's the difference between 'multipart/related' and 'multipart/form-data' and when should I use each?

Tags: http, file-upload, upload, protocols

I was able to find a lot of information about multipart/form-data but not much about multipart/related. In terms of the protocol / request format, can someone explain the differences between these two http specifications when it comes to file uploading?

Answer (score 19):

**multipart/form-data** is used to upload files of MIME-compatible representation, such as pictures and video files, and related metadata a single POST request. That's what happens when you fill in a form online with attached pictures and then press the "Submit" button.

**multipart/related** is used for compound documents and you would need to combine the separate body parts to provide the full meaning of the message. One use case would be submitting some Base64-encoded images together with the associated metadata.

One POST request sample is (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload):

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz
Content-Length: [NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_ENTIRE_REQUEST_BODY]

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "name": "myObject"
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: image/jpeg

[JPEG_DATA]
--foo_bar_baz--
```

You can find more details at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527355(v=exchg.10).aspx

Comment: `multipart/related` requires a `type` parameter identifying the primary part of the document. It's far more commonly used for HTML email or offline archives, where images etc. are included as related parts.

Comment: @OrangeDog : can you point to some specification. Also what do you mean by 'type' : is it the 'Content-Type' of each part that become mandatory ?

Comment: @sandwood https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387